# Why is this TS type recognized as a namespace?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZEaO.png)
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bElDS.png)[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHHN3.png)
I created type options when using union types, but when other files were introduced and used, they told me that it was a namespace. Is it a path configuration problem in tsconfig?

```js
//  file: src/common/requests/index.tsx
export type options<body> = RequestInit & {
    gateway? : string;
    body? : body;
};

//fileB
import { options } from 'common/requests';

//TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'options' as a type.
type option<T> = options<T>;
```

{add some more details.add some more details.add some more details.add some more details.add some more details.add some more details.add some more details.add some more details.}
tsconfig.json :

```json
{
    "compilerOptions" : {
        "allowJs" : true ,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true ,
        "allowUnusedLabels" : true ,
        "baseUrl" : "." ,
        "declaration" : true ,
        "declarationDir" : "src/common/Global DTS" ,
        "declarationMap" : true ,
        "esModuleInterop" : true ,
        "experimentalDecorators" : true ,
        "emitDeclarationOnly" : true ,
        "jsx" : "react" ,
        "resolveJsonModule" : true ,
        "strictFunctionTypes" : false ,
        "strict" : false ,
        "strictBindCallApply" : false ,
        "strictNullChecks" : false ,
        "allowUnreachableCode" : true ,
        "module" : "CommonJS" ,
        "moduleResolution" : "node" ,
        "noEmit" : true ,
        "noImplicitAny" : false ,
        "noImplicitReturns" : false ,
        "noImplicitUseStrict" : false ,
        "noUnusedLocals" : false ,
        "noUnusedParameters" : false ,
        "paths" : {
            "common/*" : [
                "/src/common/*"
            ] ,
            "common/requests" : [
                "/src/common/requests/index.ts"
            ] ,
            "common/requests/env" : [
                "/src/common/requests/ENV.ts"
            ] ,
        } ,
        "preserveConstEnums" : true ,
        "removeComments" : true ,
        "sourceMap" : true ,
        "target" : "ES2020" ,
        "watch" : true ,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true
    } 
}
```

Comment: [Please replace or supplement images of text with the plain text itself.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved my problem , delete the "/" and everything is OK

```json
 "paths" : {
            "common/*" : [
                "src/common/*"
            ] ,
            "common/requests" : [
                "src/common/requests/index.ts"
            ] ,
            "common/requests/env" : [
                "src/common/requests/ENV.ts"
            ] ,
        } ,
```